# What is maximum storage size of IIS7?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

i am making an application  in C#. In this application i am doing some calculations and putting these values into collection which is on IIS. So here i want to know how much size of data i can store on IIS?Because after sometime(in hours),my collection on IIS gets reset.

i made the collection of strings on IIS. And as per my requirement i want this collection for 4 to 5 days.After that i am resetting the collection and again making new collection.But my collection is getting reset before 4 days.I am not getting what is the problem.
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information (code snippets) about how are you storing values in IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the "Advanced Settings" of your Application Pool. I guess your Application Pool is automatically recycled, because of the "Regular Timer Interval (minutes)" setting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store "a lot" for "a long time", use a database.
The website gets reset automatically every so often.

Answer (score 3):

Your collection does not get reset. What can happen is that your application-pool recycles and this will cause your application to restart and your collection will be gone.

How often this is done can be controlled from IIS.

I am using Win2008 server 64bit and basically I can keep growing my collection until I hit the physicical memory limit (in my case 24gb).

Comment: Can you tell  me more about application-pool recycles? And how to control it?

Comment: On top most sensible hosters have application pool limits. IIs is a web server, it is NOT a database. Anyone abusing it gets what he asks for.

Comment: @TomTom - We have no idea if he is on shared hosting.

Comment: No, but even then admins may set the limti lower. It is generally ver bad to jsut wwaste space on IIS.